# Fancybox not loading certain sites given in href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I want to load certain website in fancybox. This is my code:

```
  $.fancybox({
                'width': '85%',
                'height': '85%',
                'type': 'iframe',
                'href': 'https://twitter.com',
                'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                'transitionOut': 'elastic'
             });
```

As you can see I am loading twitter.com in href. The request is sent when I saw it in Fiddler but the page doesn't render. Any idea what can be wrong?

**Note:** I am already using latest version of fancybox i.e 1.3.4.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter.com uses frame breakers because of [clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking) attempts in the past. That is probably the reason why it is not working.

If you are trying to display your feed, use their [api](https://dev.twitter.com/).

Comment: Please don't tell me the problem ;). I am not really interested in problem. Please tell me the solution.

Comment: I am not trying to display feed. I want to display login form of Twitter to the user.

Comment: THERE IS NO SOLUTION! When people use framebreakers, it is because they do not want to be framed! :)